# read last entry and find the MAX value in a string of integers

Tags: vb.net

i hope this is an easy one

as data comes in, my code builds a string of integers, separated by environment.newline

```
 2
 10
 1
 8
```

in this list the max value is 10. how do i evaluate that list of integers to discover the MAX value?

next, how do i read the last integer from the string?

TIA

Comment: how does it "come in"?

Comment: the string of integers is created using a for / next loop. i have a string of 4 #s. how does one determine the max, and how to read the last entry. Thank for the reply!

Comment: i just did a google search for (in quotes) "find the MAX value in a string of integers" ... the only hit was this thread. if something is out there and findable i dont ask. i guess everything is findable, maybe i should rate things based on the 'buried' scale, 1 being on the surface and 10 being at the bottom of a pit of quicksand 10,000 feet deep. and btw i am not a 'student' in school. if i have an answer for someone who posts on a forum i just answer it. if i dont know i dont. i dont take the time to tell someone to 'go find the answer yourself' what is the point of that?

Comment: @user2258973. some ideas: first look into "split string into array", then "find max element of array"

Comment: i would rather have no answer to a simple question than have someone who knows the answer purposely not answer because they want to make a point, which to me is really dumb. its just argumentative b_s* for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Split(InputString, environment.newline).Max()
```

and:

```
Split(InputString, environment.newline).Last()
```

Comment: well, it works sort of. the first array has these numbers: 1, 3, 28, 96, 5, 35, 6, 2, 8, 10, 1, 3, 94, 5, 38, and your code finds the MAX, 96. the next array, using the exact same code to generate it as the first has these: 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 21, 27, 1, 7, 6, 178, 41, 10, but whereas the MAX is 178, your code shows the MAX as 8. any ideas why that is happening? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: i see now that the numbers need to be integers. otherwise the results are wrong. i have to figure out a way to convert the input string into an array of integers. Thanks!

Comment: @user2258973 Max() can accept a function that can help you treat elements as Integers. Try `.Max(Function(el) CInt(el))`